# Scrolling speed with mouse position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small problem with how should i think a... problem. I want to do something somehow similar with [this](http://www.lo2k.net/v7/lab/flickr/index/flickr_id/23006509@N00): when you move mouse near to the edges, you will see images scrolling faster than how is scrolling when you have the mouse in the midle of the DIV.

Don't know if i explained right, but ... i don't know how to tackle this. I'm sure that is binded on mousemove but also i guess is somehow related to math. And math isn't my best skill :D

Thanks guys!

Comment: I would be interested in the answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's not much more to tell you than what you can already read in the source code of the site you linked from line 59 onwards. 
I'd likely recommend simply trying to duplicate something similar within your own sandbox page using that code they have as a guideline. Simply strip out everything you can and just start with a single image, bind the mousemove event and try and get relative positions using offset (see jquery - [offset](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset)).

It's a pretty nice implementation of the new canvas tag though, I haven't seen it used much yet, so thanks for passing on the link. I can at least offer you some interesting links on the [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial) [tag](http://billmill.org/static/canvastutorial/) that might give you a few pointers.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but you can calculate a procentage based on the distance between the mouse position and the edges. Then use that procentage to set the speed of the animation.